# MATLAB sending image matrix on the network

Tags: matlab, session, image-processing, network-programming

I want to create a TCP/IP session where I send an image matrix between a server session and a client session.

The code for my server session:

```
A = imread('cameraman.jpg');
[r, c]=size(A);
B = reshape(A,1,[]);%2d to 1d;
t = tcpip('0.0.0.0', 30000, 'NetworkRole', 'server');
fopen(t);
fwrite(t, B);
```

The code for my client session:

```
t = tcpip('localhost', 30000, 'NetworkRole', 'client');
fopen(t);
data = fread(t, t.BytesAvailable);
C=reshape(data,r,c)%1d to 2d;
imshow(C);
```

I opened two MATLAB Windows and ran them both, server first.

The problem is that the server program kept running with no connection to the client:

```
>> tcpserver
Error using icinterface/fwrite (line 193)
The number of bytes written must be less than or equal to OutputBufferSize-BytesToOutput.

Error in tcpserver (line 6)
fwrite(t, B);
```

And the client program gave an error:

```
>> tcpclient
Error using icinterface/fread (line 163)
SIZE must be greater than 0.

Error in tcpclient (line 3)
data = fread(t, t.BytesAvailable);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should specify the follow:

`set(t, 'OutputBufferSize', 3200);`

the `3200` value is the amount of data that you allow to send with tcp. By default it's `512`.

Let me run it and I will post again a full answer.